# How long can I use an FAA license in Colombia without having to validate it?

Tags: regulations, international, colombia

What is the maximum range of time that an FAA certificated pilot can stay and fly in Colombia, without the need to validate his license there?

Comment: What do you mean by validate?

Comment: A pilot's license typically entitels you to fly aircraft registered in your home country, no matter where you fly them. If you want to pilot a foreign-registered aircraft, they need to recognize your license first.

Comment: Every country has their own rules and requirements. You’re going to need to be a bit more specific if you’re interested in a certain country.

Comment: FAA licence in Colombia!

Answer (score 2):

You could fly US-registered aircraft in Colombia with your FAA license, but if you want to fly Colombian aircraft then you need to either validate your FAA license or get a Colombian one.

You validate your FAA license (or any ICAO license) by getting a Colombian "provisional" license. It remains valid as long as your FAA certificate and medical are valid. See [section 2.1.7 of the Colombian regulations](http://www.aerocivil.gov.co/normatividad/RAC/RAC%20%202%20-%20Personal%20%20Aeron%C3%A1utico.pdf):

> **2.1.7. CONVALIDACIÓN**
>
> Cuando la UAEAC convalide una licencia extranjera otorgada por un
>   Estado contratante de la OACI, en vez de otorgar su propia licencia,
>   hará constar la convalidación mediante autorización apropiada que
>   constará en una licencia provisional la cual deberá acompañar a la
>   licencia extranjera y reconocerá ésta como equivalente a las otorgadas
>   por dicha autoridad aeronáutica colombiana. La validez de la
>   autorización no podrá exceder el plazo de validez  de la licencia
>   extranjera.

Note that the process of validation depends on your personal situation, especially whether or not you plan to become a Colombian resident (see 2.1.7.1).

Comment: Did you just know that or are you a research monster? :-)

Comment: @Pugz That's research :-)

Comment: it’s beautiful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

24 Calendar months, as you will need a [Biennial Flight Review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biennial_flight_review) although you could potentially do this abroad if you could find an FAA instructor abroad.

If you have a question I would reach out to the [FAA staffer stationed in Columbia](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/apl/contact_us/country_contacts/)

> [Colombia](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/apl/contact_us/country_contacts/)
>
> Veronica Carpio   (202) 267-0965
>   Carl N. Johnson   507-317-5046